# Which and all libraries are OS/platform-independent?

Tags: c++, operating-system, libraries

Is there any library which doesn't use operating system calls for it's functionalities? If I'm writing an OS can cherry pick any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Newlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newlib) is an implementation of the standard library for embedded systems. It tries to be as portable as possible. Even so, it still requires you to implement a number platform specific functions for each platform you'd like to run it on.

I would say that no, the standard libraries aren't platform independent. If you'd like to know which changes you should make for your port, look at: http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib

Comment: Thank you! that makes some sense.